# python 3 django shell ipython bug. ipython shell wouldn't run

Tags: django, ipython, python-3.4

At some point my project has stoped running IPython shell. ./manage.py shell --plain however still works fine. Unfortunately i don't remember exactly at what moment that happened but it might be due to some packages conflicting with each other. I am running my project in a virtualenv, other virtualenv's with common package set-up work just fine.

Here is the error traceback:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 81, in handle_noargs
    self.run_shell(shell=interface)
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 61, in run_shell
    return getattr(self, shell)()
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 44, in ipython
    ip()
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 37, in _ipython
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 35, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 47, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magics import ScriptMagics
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .execution import ExecutionMagics
  File "/home/pk/.virtualenvs/eissvedvl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py", line 27, in <module>
    import cProfile as profile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/cProfile.py", line 22, in <module>
    run.__doc__ = _pyprofile.run.__doc__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'
```

Here is my requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.6.5
South==1.0
Werkzeug==0.9.6
django-admin-bootstrapped==1.6.6
django-ajax-selects==1.3.5
django-allauth==0.18.0
django-braces==1.4.0
django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
django-extensions==1.3.11
ipython==2.3.0
oauthlib==0.6.3
psycopg2==2.5.3
requests==2.4.3
requests-oauthlib==0.4.2
six==1.7.3
```

I would appreciate any help to solve the issue. I have already tried to use different versions of IPython but the shell still wouldn't start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maybe in your code package name `profile`. Refactor your code